# Making hashbrowns with butter?

Tags: oil, butter

I'm wondering if anyone has had success with hash browns by the way of butter.

I've read certain sources claim that it's OK to use butter, some suggest only using it with oil, but I detest the flavor I receive when preparing with any oil.

Is it possible at all?

P.S. - I'm referring to [this](https://youtu.be/LA_UgRxWsnw?t=6m18s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer buttered hashbrowns myself. I've had the best luck with unsalted butter and by cooking them on medium to medium low heat so they won't burn or over brown quickly.

If you are making hashbrowns from scratch make sure you remove all the excess moisture as this will further aid in golden brown color instead of burning.

Answer (score 1):

I don't make hash browns (I know -GASP- how can I call myself a cook). At the higher frying temperatures that give a nice browned crust, butter burns. But clarified butter or ghee can be heated much higher without burning - comparable to most oils. After all, it's not actual butterfat that's burning but the solid milk components. It will still have the butter flavour you want.

Indian cooks usually make their own ghee but it can also be bought in stores. But clarifying your own butter is ridiculously simple so I'm including a link explaining how. [How To Make Clarified Butter](http://www.davidlebovitz.com/how-to-clarify-butter-recipe/)